# copy paste range into next column and update

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

column B gets data updated

column C onwards is used to store consolidated data

im trying to copy a range of data to right next column

and update column C with data from column B

```
function doUpBCL() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BLC');

  var data_new = ss.getRange('B1').getDisplayValue();  
  var data_old = ss.getRange('C1').getDisplayValue();  

  if( data_new !== data_old )  // check if data changed
  {

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
    
  var data = ss.getRange(1,3,lr,lc - 3).getValues();
  ss.getRange(1,4,lr,lc - 4).setValues(data);

  var data_ = ss.getRange(lr,2,1,1).getValues();
  ss.getRange(lr,3,1,1).setValues(data_);
    
  }   

};
```

macro (created by Google Sheets) as EXAMPLE to ilustrate what i want is (i need help with above function, not this)

```
function upblc_macro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BLC'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C:Z').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B:B').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

using last row cos im going to use similar funcions to other pages and im trying to funcion where i dont have to adjust everytime

simply add new column, move or append to last column wont work the way i need

help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C:Z').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);` D:D is one column C:Z is 24 columns

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: that macro was created by google sheet. i selected the range i wanted to copy, then selected start destination, then paste, basicly coping everything 1 column to the right, trying to create a function script to do that, but its not working

Comment: function copyCol() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};

Comment: forget about that macro, that was just to ilustrate my intention, the above function is what i actually need help

Comment: Well I find the wording of your question difficult to understand so perhaps you could paste some images of your spreadsheet showing before an after and use the images to help explain to us what you want to what you want to do. Also in general we really dislike you posting pictures of code or code inside of comments we have a really nice facility for posting the code in the question learn how to use it use it.

Comment: yea perhaps the way i described wasnt the best way, but i did try to provide as much information on what i needed as possible (posting GS macro aparently didnt help) and did what i could to solve myself my problem before asking for advice, although something i didnt do was post picture of code or code in the comments,  anyway managed to solve issue and posted as reply for future reference, regards and thanks

Answer (score 0):

with lots of tries and errors, with a few tweaks and minor changes, i managed to make it work as i wanted

```
function doUpBCL() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BLC');
  
  const data_new = ss.getRange('B1').getDisplayValue();  
  const data_old = ss.getRange('C1').getDisplayValue();  

  if( data_new !== data_old )  // check if data changed
  {

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
    
  const data = ss.getRange(1,3,lr,lc-2).getValues();
  ss.getRange(1,4,lr,lc-2).setValues(data);

  const data_ = ss.getRange(1,2,lr,1).getValues();
  ss.getRange(1,3,lr,1).setValues(data_);
    
  }  
  
  else
    {
    }

};
```

not sure why of some stuff i changed, some other stuff i learned, but still learning